# Accessing raw faust/kafka message while using take method

Tags: python, faust

I have a need to batch the events in a Faust stream, so I'm using the `take()` method. However, I would also like to access the header message, particularly a timestamp.

Ordinarily  you would access the header using:

```py
async for event in stream.events()
```

and then call the header using `event.header`, but since we're using the take method:

```py
async for event in stream.take(500, 1)
```

we can't seem to get access to the raw message. Any idea on how to get this? We're just trying to have a means of highlighting a slow section of the pipeline by monitoring timestamps of each as a header, rather than adding it as a part of the `value` part of the sent message.

Is there another raw timestamp that's 'hidden' but accessible that I've missed?

**EDIT**

Using faust-streaming==0.8.4 so it's definitely up to date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Event](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/blob/26ff8fc6d98a9154b5fe9b4daad5610314b0144b/faust/types/events.py#L35) and [Message](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/blob/26ff8fc6d98a9154b5fe9b4daad5610314b0144b/faust/types/tuples.py#L123) objects have headers as attributes that can be accessed in a stream. Both `events` and `take` utilize `EventT` objects so you should be able to access them the same way. The only difference is that `take` and its derivatives unpack `EventT` objects into dicts inside a buffer list whereas `events` yields an individual `EventT` at a time. You can individually access `EventT` objects if you set your `take` buffer size to 1.

There's a function introduced in `faust-streaming==0.7.7` called [`stream.take_with_timestamp`](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/blob/7cc93e8f1e8fc65ce7664c3c229b59c259b05e95/faust/streams.py#L394) that's nearly identical to `stream.take` that can be utilized via:

```
async for event in stream.take_with_timestamp(1, 1, 'timestamp'):
  print(stream.current_event)
  if stream.current_event is not None:
    print(stream.current_event.headers)
    print(stream.current_event.message.headers)
```

which will show you the timestamp of each `event`. The caveat here is that if you set the buffer set to anything >1 and your stream times out, your `stream.current_event` object will be `None`.

Or you could just mimic the assignments inside `take_with_timestamp` and access `event.message.timestamp` inside `stream.events()`:

```
async for event in stream.events():
  print(event.message.timestamp)
  print(event.headers)
  print(event.message.headers)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I appear to get the following: `AttributeError: 'Stream' object has no attribute 'take_with_timestamp'`. I assume it means I'm not using the correct version? Also, I can't access the raw message as described in the second suggestion (stream.events(), then event.message.timestamp), i end up with a key error - message isn't in my event. It's like i'm only getting the value part of the message. Again, the timestamp is not part of the data message I need to forward on, but is an add on at the time of processing purely for time stamping.

Comment: As an example, here's the printed output from events when using `async for events in stream.events()`:  `[<AlarmEventFreq: alarm_id=1, sevr='MAJOR', stat='some status', val='alarm value', datetime='2022-05-28 11:13:56.291803', counts_10=1, counts_30=1, counts_60=1, counts_300=1, in_alarm_since='2022-05-28 11:01:01.158031'>]`. I also can't read the header from the event by inspecting each element in the list.

Comment: I did some research and `take_with_timestamp` was introduced in the release of v0.7.7 of faust-streaming. Thanks for editing your question to indicate you're using v0.8.4. I'm not sure where you see the latest release of v0.6.4 when [GitHub says the latest is v0.8.4](https://github.com/faust-streaming/faust/releases). I'll edit my answer to address your requested header events.

Comment: Thanks. I had to upgrade my version and the method is now supported, and then forgot to restart my kernel so was still using the old version. Re version# I must be looking in the wrong place. But when I try to print the event with the new method, I still only get the list of events, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks again @wbarnha. Unfortuantely that's not a workable solution if the `within` value has to be set so low. We can make do without it as it was only to be used to flag a slow pipeline process. If we really need it we can add in a timestamp at each section before passing the enriched data onto the next topic.